# Use promises to get a JSON file

Tags: node.js, promise

I'm new to promises and I have a few questions about these.

I needed to get a JSON file (with weather things) for my node.js app from a url so I made a `getJSON()` function that uses the https module `const https = require('https');` that "returns" the file:

```
function getJSON(url, resolve) {
    https.get(url, function(res) {
        let json = '';
        res.on('data', function(chunk) { json += chunk; });
        res.on('end', function() { resolve(JSON.parse(json)); });
    }).on('error', function(err) { console.log(err); });
};
```

And as you can see it does not actually returns the value but it resolves it, because i'm calling the function with a promise:

```
function weather() {
    let json = new Promise(function(res) {getJSON('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?APPID=APIKEY&q=City&units=metric', res);})
                json.then(function(weatherJSON) {
                    // and here i can use the file
                });
}
```

So this works, but I feel like it could be way better, could I optimize this ? May I should not even use promises ?

Thanks!

Comment: In your code, what is `https`?

Comment: Oh oops I forgot to say, I'm using node.js and https is `const https = require('https');`

Comment: Don't use the `https` module and re-implement everything from scratch. `https` is very low-level and more convenient options exist, with full promise support. Look at `request-promise-native` for example. https://github.com/request/request-promise-native

Comment: Ok, I'll get this a try, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well this question, you shoud return a promise in your method.

```
function getJSON(url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        const req = https.get(url, res => {
            let json = '';
            res.on('data', function(chunk) { json += chunk; });
            res.on('end', function() { resolve(JSON.parse(json)); });
        });
        req.on('error', function(err) { console.log(err); });
    });
};

    const weather = () => {

        getJSON('yourURL')
            .then((data) => console.log(data))
            .catch((error) => console.error(error));
    }
```

Comment: The syntax on the promise return was wrong but I fixed it and it works!

`return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {`

Comment: When encountering an error in a promise, you should reject the promise. That way in the `catch` callback, your error can be handled there.